# Correlation Matrix in "R" returning NA values

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, na

I have a spreadsheet with 23 variables and 480 entries.  Some of the entries are complete for every variable and others have no data for some of the variables.  What format should I save this spreadsheet in to run a correlation matrix successfully on the variables?  I have an older version that has all variables filled out and it works with this code:

```
setwd("/Users/user/Desktop/R")
dat <- read.delim("data.txt",header=T) #data was saved from an Excel to a .txt but forgot specifics
attributes(dat)["names"]
dat <- dat[,-13]
library(car)
cor(dat[,c("bd","precip","freq","depth")]) #"bd" etc. are column headings/variable names
```

This code with this data txt file provides a beautiful correlation matrix populated with values that make sense.  Now that I have added more variables I cannot get correlation values - it just returns NA for everything except the 1:1 correlations.

I tried variables that had all values populated and that did not work.
I tried populating values that were sketchy for all variables in the data for all entries just to try it and it still gave me the NA everywhere.

Not sure if it is the way I am saving the file.  Cannot remember how I originally saved the file, but it is coming from a spreadsheet in Excel that I am saving as a txt file.  Anyone have any ideas how I can get values here instead of NA?  Would be much appreciated!!

Comment: 1. print out your data to see if it looks as you expect. 2. check if it has any NAs inside it - that would produce NA correlation matrix. 3. check the types of all columns - they should be numeric, not factors.

Comment: Without reproducible code, I'm just guessing... 1. Try `dat <- dat[complete.cases(dat), ]` (this will remove any rows with NA values) then do `cor(dat)`. 2. Do `cor(dat, use="pairwise.complete.obs")`. See if that works. Then read `?cor` to see if that operation is reasonable for your dataset.

Comment: THANK YOU! bdemarest you're answer #1 works perfectly ... When I save the text file it must be including an extra row or something ... Regradless ... its working now.  THANK YOU SO MUCH!